# DC isolation fault circuit breaker feasibility - design review

Tags: circuit-protection

So I was wondering what the best way is to interrupt ground faults in ground isolated DC circuits. After some research, I found out about isolation fault detectors and was wondering if one could use a circuit like the one below to achieve the same functionality.

The circuit basically works by weakly pulling the PE to half the supply voltage. The voltage of the PE line in reference to the circuit GND is then monitored for much lower/higher than half of the supply voltage.

[image]

The circuit is supposed to go in between a solar array and an isolated 230V grid tied inverter. Its only job is to detect ground faults in the DC wiring (short to earth -> cable insulation defective -> possible danger for unlucky homo sap.)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the field, but I think it might be useful to expand your question to describe the nature of the load and the reason for wanting to ensure isolation. (Especially when your proposal of "weakly pulling" makes the circuit "weakly non-isolated".)

Comment: The circuit is supposed to go in between a solar array and an isolated 230V grid tied inverter. Its only job is to detect ground faults in the DC wiring (short to Earth -> Cable insulation defective -> possible danger for unlucky homo sap.).

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the information into your question — in the future, when clarification is requested, please make sure to [edit] and not just leave a comment. Ideally, comments should be able to be deleted once improvements have been made.